Bookmarks: \Part and \textgreek with dgruyter.sty
I am finalizing a book using XeLaTeX and the dgruyter.sty package (I cannot share it). Everything is ready except for the bookmarks, which are behaving oddly in their output in two cases:

When I use the command \part{}, the output bookmark is displayed as "Numbers=MonospacedTeil[Title]" or even "Numbers=MonospacedTeil” with no title (!).
When I use the command \textgreek{αβγ} (which I defined, see below), the output bookmark is shown as "greekἔχω". In normal text, \textgreek{αβγ} works perfectly.

For the second point, I have followed the recommendations from here but encountered an error both with \usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} and \usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}: "LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref".
Does anyone have suggestions on how to solve these bookmark issues? An example follows.
Thank you!
   % !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[twoside,openany]{book}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} 
\usepackage{babel}
\babelfont[greek]{rm}{De Gruyter Serif}\newfontfamily\myfont{De Gruyter Serif}
\usepackage[medium]{dgruyter}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]{%
\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}#1\end{otherlanguage*}}

\begin{document}

\part{Introduction}
\chapter{A problem with \textgreek{ἔχω}}

Here is the problem!

\end{document}

As requested below, my .log follows (I have already integrated the solution for \textgreek{}, as explained by Marijn):
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/De-Gruyter-Serif-Regular.otf(4)/b/n' undefin
ed
(Font)              using `TU/De-Gruyter-Serif-Regular.otf(4)/m/n' instead on i
nput line 29.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/latinmodern-math.otf(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.53662pt on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/latinmodern-math.otf(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 7.027pt on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/latinmodern-math.otf(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 5.01927pt on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/latinmodern-math.otf(3)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.53459pt on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/latinmodern-math.otf(3)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 7.02548pt on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/latinmodern-math.otf(3)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 5.01819pt on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+rsfs on input line 29
.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd
File: ursfs.fd 1998/03/24 rsfs font definition file (jk)
)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/rsfs/m/n' in size <9.53561> not available
(Font)              size <10> substituted on input line 29.

[3] (./Senza-nome.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 0.46439pt have occurred.


LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 19237 strings out of 476473
 354482 string characters out of 5816481
 863952 words of memory out of 5000000
 39340 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 406761 words of font info for 117 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 76i,6n,132p,337b,2766s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on Senza-nome.pdf (3 pages).


show your log-file.

Thanks for the log file, it is not complete though - the part at the beginning is missing, which contains a lot of important information on the engine, package versions etc.

You are right, sorry; however, I cannot upload everything because it exceeds the number of characters available for my post...

@Giacomo since the two issues are different you can also edit this question to focus only on the Greek part (which I have answered) and delete everything about \part, and ask a new question only about \part for which you remove as much code as possible while still reproducing the issue. If the code is shorter and focuses on one issue then the log file will be shorter as well, so it might fit in the new question. If it still doesn't fit then trim the log file yourself by deleting highly similar messages - for example here you can reduce the six 'scaled to size' messages to just one.

Can you at least tell us the version of dgruyter.sty you are using? There is a publicly available version 2.0, saying 2017/09/19 v2.00 De Gruyter layout. It should be somewhere in the first 20 lines of dgruyter.sty

Disclaimer: the official De Gruyter style file is not freely available from the publisher online, so I used a 2017 version that I found somewhere. However, I expect that the solution will work for other versions as well.
For the PDF bookmarks the general solution is to use the macro \texorpdfstring{}{}. This macro can be used to provide two versions of a string, the first argument is used by LaTeX itself for typesetting (i.e., what you see on the page) and the second argument is used as PDF bookmark for the table of contents in the PDF viewer (or anywhere else outside of the page).
In this case that would be
\chapter{A problem with \texorpdfstring{\textgreek{ἔχω}}{ἔχω}}

This would expand to A problem with \textgreek{ἔχω} for use with LaTeX and to A problem with ἔχω for use as a PDF bookmark. Because PDF readers natively handle non-latin scripts this is displayed correctly.
However, you can also set the fonts for the entire document using fontspec. The De Gruyter fonts contain Greek so once they are set with \setmainfont and possibly \setsansfont (for titles) then you don't need to put any commands around them to display correctly everywhere (in titles, in pdf bookmarks, in the main text). Note that using Babel for fonts in the main text may still be preferable because it provides other setting for the language, such as hyphenation.
In the code below I explicitly set each variant with the full file name of the font, because XeLaTeX has problems finding the correct fonts otherwise - if that already works on your system then you can probably just use \setmainfont{De Gruyter Serif} and \setsansfont{De Gruyter Sans}, or, with a bit of luck, just \setmainfont{De Gruyter}.
I showed an example of using ἔχω directly in a title, and with \textgreek in the title (which indeed does not work in the pdf bookmark), and with \texorpdfstring in the title of a section, and used directly inside \textsf (sans).
\documentclass[twoside,openany]{book}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
 BoldFont={De-Gruyter-Serif-Bold.otf}, 
 ItalicFont={De-Gruyter-Serif-Italic.otf},
 BoldItalicFont={De-Gruyter-Serif-Bold-Italic.otf}
 ]{De-Gruyter-Serif-Regular.otf}
\setsansfont[
 BoldFont={De-Gruyter-Sans-Bold.otf}, 
 ItalicFont={De-Gruyter-Sans-Italic.otf},
 BoldItalicFont={De-Gruyter-Sans-Bold-Italic.otf}
 ]{De-Gruyter-Sans-Regular.otf}
\usepackage{babel}
\babelfont[greek]{rm}{De-Gruyter-Serif-Regular.otf}\newfontfamily\myfont{De-Gruyter-Serif-Regular.otf}
\usepackage[medium]{dgruyter}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]{%
\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}#1\end{otherlanguage*}}

\begin{document}

\part{Introduction}
\chapter{A ἔχω problem with \textgreek{ἔχω}}

Here is the ἔχω problem! \textgreek{ἔχω}

\textsf{In sf this is the ἔχω problem}.

\section{A problem with \texorpdfstring{\textgreek{ἔχω}}{ἔχω}}

\end{document}

Result:

Note that I could not reproduce the problem with \part in the bookmarks. Possibly you have a LaTeX error somewhere that you have ignored and that causes the behavior. Otherwise there may be differences in your version of the De Gruyter style - which we might be able to spot if you post the contents of the log file as requested by Ulrike.

Wonderful! Thank you so much. This has indeed solved the problem with the Greek. I am now adding the contents of the .log file to my post for the problem with \part{}.

hmm, I am preparing a paper for a DeGruyter journal, and indeed, I can only find a 2017 version of the .sty file. Which is broken in many ways.

@DimaPasechnik I assume that the way to get a recent version of the .sty file is to actually make an account at De Gruyter and start the submission process, and then they will provide a link with the style, as evidenced by the OP of this question saying that he has the file but he "cannot share it". But sometimes publishers just want you to submit the paper without any style applied, i.e., just \documentclass{article}, and when it is accepted they will produce the correct layout and send it to you for proofing.

the paper is already accepted, I do have an account, but I can't find a good version of dgruyter.sty (only the 7 years old one)

given that they swim in money, I can't imagine the reason for not keeping an up do date version public, too. Someone fixed it, and retained copyright, which they cannot buy out? Really?
I got SPMA_LaTex Template.zip - SPMA stands for Special Matrices - so this looks like an official package for authors. But it's open, and contains that outdated .sty file

the fonts in question are public, at https://gitlab.com/degruyter-public/font - as far as I can see.

@DimaPasechnik It is probably best to ask the editor of the journal which files you should use and where to get them. If they tell you to use the old version then you will have to fix or work around any issues you encounter - but maybe it isn't that bad and the editor will point you to an updated version.

It's an APC-paid journal - APC paid by my employer, otherwise I'd not be bothered. For that money they certainly should be providing this kind of support.
The old version is incompatible with the recent versions of listings package, and in general fonts support is messed up, e.g. some of tables in the text get numerical entries in bold, but maths in captions is mostly just white space. That's a quite a bit  of work to fix...

@DimaPasechnik most likely they do have some sort of author support, where you can ask (technical) questions about preparing your manuscript, including incompatibilities that you may encounter. The editor can help you reach out to them. Surely they have had authors that used listings or math in captions before, so there will be solutions available.

yeah, support of kind "Please find the zip file attached" with the same old stuff from 2017 as is online...
